# Find the real path of a shared URL

Tags: folder, url, path, sharing

This is a SIMPLE user question, not a coding one. I get SharePoint FILE links all the time, where it opens the file. Unfortunately, figuring out what folder path it is in seems impossible.

Is there an easy way to decipher that?  Otherwise, I will just have to keep reminding folks to share the PATH of the file, not the URL to open the file.

Thanks so much!

A novice user.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint files can be access via a web URL. So to find that URL you can open the browser, then type the SharePoint site url. Then choose the library/folder you uploaded the file.

Then you can right click the file and copy the URL. You can validate the URL by putting the URL in a new tab, which will open the file.

Another option is to open the library which has the file in Explorer (You can use Library tab from the ribbon and click on open in explorer button). Then copy the file path.

Comment: The problem is - I am sent a file whose URL directly opens the file itself.  I need to know into what folder it was original put.  I have to edit and then replace the file.  Looking at the URL doesn't tell me the path.

Answer (score 0):

try to get the link by right clicking on the words that has the link embedded in it and open in new window. Go to the address in the browser and remove the name of the document up to the first forward slash and hit enter which should take you to the hidden document dump library.